# \string command behavior - Plain TeX

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, strings

I would like to learn Plain TeX and I'm reading Knuth's "The TeXBook". At Chapter 7, Knuth talks about the `\string` command and how it converts control sequences into lists of characters tokens.

Why when I typed  `\string\TeX`, I got `"TeX`, but when I wrote `{\tt \string\TeX}` I got `\TeX` ?

I guess it's something related to `\escapechar`, because when I changed that control sequence the output changed too:

```
\escapechar=`^
\string\TeX
```

it generates `^TeX`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The ASCII code of `\` is 92, and this is also TeX's internal code for the backslash. Now have a look at Appendix F of the TeXbook (**F** like Font Tables). There you see that the typewriter font `cmtt10` indeed has a `\` sitting in position 92 (which is ´134 in octal notation), whereas the standard text font `cmr10` has a quotation mark `“` in that position. The reason for the latter is that in a standard text you'll need quotation marks quite often, but hardly ever a backslash.

If you want to procude the font tables yourself, use the following code (thanks to [Stefan Kottwitz](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=22516) for the suggestion!):

```
\documentclass{article}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1cm}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\fonttable{cmr10}
\fonttable{cmtt10}
\end{document}
```

[image: font tables]

Answer (score 29):

Hendrik's answer is great. Nevertheless, please allow me to elaborate on `\string` and `\escapechar` a little more:

Like you said the `\string` primitive converts a control sequence into a list of character tokens<sup>1</sup>. It also works on other tokens and turns them into their string representation. Two things are notable here: All characters with the exception of spaces are returned as *category code* (catcode) 12 "other", even if their where from catcode 11 "letter" beforehand. If the control sequence contained spaces (possible with `\csname .. \endcsname`) then they have still catcode 10 "space". This catcode change has no influence on typesetting or `\write`ing these characters.

Secondly, the backslash in the control sequence is not stored by TeX with every control sequence name. The backslash is only required to mark a control sequence as one and once that got tokenized it is no longer required. Also the backslash is not hard wired into TeX. Every character with the catcode 0 "escape character" will work. However by default the backslash is the only one character with this catcode.
Because TeX doesn't store the escape character used for every particular control sequence it needs to get told how to represent it when it has to turn the control sequence back into a string. This is done using the `\escapechar` register<sup>2</sup> which holds the ASCII number of the used character. By default it is that to 92 which is the number for the backslash. This register can be changed at will. If it contains a negative number, no escape character will be produced by `\string` at all. This fact is often used by (La)TeX code which like to get the macro name only. Has Hendrik already wrote in his great answer, you need to make sure that the escape character is available in the currently used font. Usually you are right when using a tt font.

So, for example `` \escapechar=`\A\catcode`\|=0 |string|foo `` will output `Afoo`, not `\foo` or `|foo`. After the catcode change TeX doesn't care here if you use `|` or `\` and you can mix them as you want (Note that `\\` can be written as `|\` now but not as `||` because the second backslash is not an escape character). You are also not forced to keep `\escapechar` to a character of catcode 0.

---

<sup>1</sup>) Knuth, *The TeXBook*, page 40, paragraph 1, Chapter 7: *How TEX Reads What You Type*.
 <sup>2</sup>) Knuth, *The TeXBook*, page 40, paragraph 6, Chapter 7: *How TEX Reads What You Type*.

Answer (score 20):

### The theory

How does `\string` work? There are various cases, but first of all one must be aware that it's a primitive command of TeX which just looks at the next token *without expanding it*. This lookup happens *after* the tokenization process, which can transform the input in various ways.

So we are interested in the expansion of `\string<token>`

1. If `<token>` is a character of any category code except 10 (including active characters) , the expansion is the same character with category code 12. Note, however, that `<token>` can't have category 0, 9, 14 or 15, because such characters never reach the "mouth" where expansion takes place.
2. If `<token>` is a character of category code 10, the expansion is the pair (32,10), that is, a normal space token of category code 10.
3. If `<token>` is a character with code 32 and any category code, the expansion is the pair (32,10), as in the preceding case.
4. If `<token>` is a control sequence, then the expansion of `\string<token>` is the control sequence's name preceded by the character having character code equal to the current value of `\escapechar`. All characters in this expansion will have category code 12, except spaces that are normalized to normal space tokens with character code 32 and category code 10. The control sequence needn't be defined and it won't be stored in the hash table.
5. However, if the value of `\escapechar` is less than 0 or greater than 255, no character will be added at the start of the returned string. The upper limit is 2097151, that is `0x1FFFFF`, for XeTeX and LuaTeX.

### Examples

1. The input

   ```
   \edef\x{\string a}\ifcat\x a\message{11}\else\message{12}\fi
   ```

   will return 12
2. The input

   ```
   \catcode`?=10 \def\temp{?}\edef\x{\expandafter\string\temp}\show\x
   ```

   will return

   ```
   > \x=macro:
   -> .
   ```
3. The input

   ```
   \catcode`\ =12 \edef\x{\string }%
   \ifcat\x\space\message{10}\else\message{12}\fi
   ```

   will return 10
4. The input

   ```
   \edef\x{\string\foo}\show\x
   ```

   will return

   ```
   > \x=macro:
   ->\foo.
   ```

   (the missing space between `o` and `.` shows that `\foo` isn't a control sequence). Instead `` \escapechar=`A \edef\x{\string\foo}\show\x `` will return

   ```
   > Ax=macro:
   ->Afoo.
   ```
5. The input

   ```
   \escapechar=-1 \edef\x{\string\foo}\show\x
   ```

   will return

   ```
   > \x=macro:
   ->foo.
   ```

   (without any character before `foo`)

### Printing

The question about the printed output of `\string\foo` is a different story; if one says `` \char`\\ ``, TeX will print whatever character is in slot 92 of the current font, which might be a backslash or not. It isn't in the standard Plain TeX font `\tenrm`, that is `cmr10`, but it is in `cmtt10`. The same will happen when printing the string resulting from `\string\foo`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem mentioned here is unrelated to the `\string` TeX primitive behavior but it is related to the fact, that Computer modern text fonts don't respect the ASCII encoding (the exception is the typewriter Computer Modern fonts, they respect ASCII). The exceptions from ASCII are at 7 slots:

- `<` is printed as ¡
- `>` is printed as ¿
- `\` is printed as “
- `{` is printed as –
- `|` is printed as —
- `}` is printed as ”
- `$` is printed as £ in cursive variants of the fonts

Moreover, the characters `\`, `{`, `}`, `$` have a special category code in plain TeX (and in other formats too), so you cannot simply write them if you want to print them.

The reason of not respecting ASCII in these seven occurrences was: few slots in used 7bit (128 slots) Computer Modern fonts and the need to implement common typographical characters not included in ASCII table. Why Knuth didn't use 8bit fonts (256 slots)? They occupy more space in TeX memory and Knuth needed to preload many fonts from Computer Modern family. The memory of computers was very limited in the days when TeX born. It was supposed that `<`, `|`, and `>` will be used only in math mode (where the font and slot selecting is done by another principles than in text font) and a special macro should be used for printing \ , { , } , $.

Now, this problem belongs only to TeX history, because we typically don't use Computer Modern fonts and use Unicode fonts (1114111 available slots). If someone comes across this problem discussed here then it means that (s)he immersed himself in the study of historical software (40 years old) and doesn't use current modern TeX.