# What does `\escapechar` do?

Tags: macros, counters, latex-base

In `latex.ltx` you can find several situations where `\escapechar` is set to -1 -- from what it's clear that it has to be a count register. But, what does it actually "count" or control? A small discussion of an example like the following could be useful too.

```
\def\renew@command#1{%
  \begingroup \escapechar\m@ne\xdef\@gtempa{{\string#1}}\endgroup
  \expandafter\@ifundefined\@gtempa
     {\@latex@error{\noexpand#1undefined}\@ehc}%
     \relax
  \let\@ifdefinable\@rc@ifdefinable
  \new@command#1}
```

Comment: From *TeX by Topic*: `\escapechar`: Number of the character that is to be used for the escape character when control sequences are being converted into character tokens. IniTeX default: 92 (``\``).

Comment: @clemens has already given you the answer.  Note, however, that `\escapechare` is *not* a `\count` register (or, better, a `\countdef` token), but an <integer parameter> (thus, a TeX primitive), listed among the others on page 273 of _The TeXbook_.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti, thank you for pointing this out. It's indeed a difference...

Comment: @clemens, in the meantime I ran a few examples too and I think I understand now. Wanna add a short answer (involving a brief discussion how `\escapechar` "strips" the backslash away in the definition of `\renew@command`)?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96620/string-command-behavior-plain-tex  Martin Scharrer answer

Comment: @touhami, so we close this one with a link to Martins answer?