# How to write ^(caret) in latex?

Tags: symbols, characters

It's as the title says. How can I write ^(caret) in Latex.

If I type something like `[^set]`, then the s in set is raised to a power. How can I display [^set] the way it is?

`$\wedge$` sorta works but it gives ∧ and not ^.

Comment: not clear what you want or if you want math mode, but perhaps `$^{\wedge}\mathrm{set}$`

Answer (score 5):

Use `\string^` that makes the argument category code 12 (other).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

text mode: [\string^set]

math mode: $[\string^set]$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're using caret often enough, you can define a shorthand macro for that

```
\newcommand{\caret}{\string^}
```

---

Read more about `\string` in this detailed [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96648/213149) by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg).

Answer (score 3):

In a simple way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

this is a caret \^{}which is over a space. % space after \^ is not mandatory


$\hat{ }x+1$

\end{document}
```

[image: Carets]