# \string\noindent outputs a quotation mark " instead of a backslash \

Tags: verbatim, strings, typewriter

I used `\string\noindent` to output a command `\noindent`, but the result is `"noindent`.
I also tried with `\verb|\noindent|` and `\texttt{\noindent}`, but the results are the same.
I found a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96620/string-command-behavior-plain-tex) may be related to my problem, but I don't know how to fix it.
Any suggestion is appreciated!

minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}

\verb|\noindent|
\string\noindent
\texttt{\noindent}

\end{document}
```

Update: I found that this result is because I use libertine font: `\usepackage{libertine}`. I deleted it and everything is fine. But I am still confused about the principle behind it.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Always show a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) so that we can see which environment you're working in, and test your code to suggest modifications.

Comment: @Miyase Updated.

Comment: OT1? ------------

Comment: Related question [punctuation - Why do the less than symbol (<) and the greater than symbol (>) appear wrong as upside down exclamation (¡) or question mark (¿)? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/why-do-the-less-than-symbol-and-the-greater-than-symbol-appear-wrong-as)

Comment: As @user202729 hints, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` should fix your problem. `\texttt{\noindent}` presumably doesn't do what you want...

Comment: Insightful answer. Thank you! @frougon

Comment: @user202729 Exactly. [T1] works! Thanks!

Comment: Generally-speaking people don't get tripped up by this particular character, because it's hard to "accidentally" get a catcode-11 or 12 (← if you want to understand this statement read e.g. TeXbook) character of backslash. The "official" method to typeset a backslash is [`\textbackslash`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9365/250119)

Comment: the standard latex syntax would be `\verb|\noindent|` which would have worked even in OT1 encoding