# Very weird results using macro inside data make

Tags: csvsimple

I am trying to test some macros inside csv data and I am obtaining very special results.

Test number 1 (look at the command `\csvautobooktabular{macrodata.csv}`):

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{book}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}


\begin{filecontents*}{macrodata.csv}
type,description,content
M,A nice \textbf{formula}, $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{x} = \ln|x|+c$
G,A \textcolor{red}{colored} ball, {\tikz \shadedraw [shading=ball] (0,0) circle (.5cm);}
M,\textbf{Another} formula, $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$
\end{filecontents*}    


\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    clé,nom,valeur
    var1,numeric,32+1
    var2,string,"text"
    var3,float,3.14-x
    var4,Latex,test
\end{filecontents*}

\csvautobooktabular{macrodata.csv} 

\section{Variables}\label{sec:var}

    \begin{landscape}
     \csvloop{
        file=data.csv,
        respect all,
        separator=comma,
        no head,
        column names={1=\cola, 2=\colb, 3=\colc},
        before reading={
            \begin{table}
                \centering
                \begin{tabular}{llr}
                    \toprule
                },
                command={\csviffirstrow
                    {\textbf{\cola} & \textbf{\colb} & \textbf{\colc}}
                    {\addtocounter{csvrow}{-1}\hyperref[sec:a-\thecsvrow]{\cola}\addtocounter{csvrow}{1} & \colb & \colc}
                },
                late after line=\\,
                late after first line=\\\midrule,
                late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
                after reading={
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Liste des entités}
                \label{tab:variables}
            \end{table}
        }
    }
    \end{landscape}
    
    
    
    \subsection{Variable 1}\label{sec:a-1}
    \dots
    
    \subsection{Variable 2}\label{sec:a-2}
    \dots
    
    \subsection{Variable 3}\label{sec:a-3}
    \dots
    
    \subsection{Variable 4}\label{sec:a-4}
    \dots\newline


   

    
\end{document}
```

This test seems to work correctly:

[image]

Now the second test:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{book}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}


\begin{filecontents*}{macrodata.csv}
type,description,content
M,A nice \textbf{formula}, $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{x} = \ln|x|+c$
G,A \textcolor{red}{colored} ball, {\tikz \shadedraw [shading=ball] (0,0) circle (.5cm);}
M,\textbf{Another} formula, $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$
\end{filecontents*}    


\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    clé,nom,valeur
    var1,numeric,32+1
    var2,string,"text"
    var3,float,3.14-x
    var4,Latex,test
\end{filecontents*}



\section{Variables}\label{sec:var}

    \begin{landscape}
     \csvloop{
        file=data.csv,
        respect all,
        separator=comma,
        no head,
        column names={1=\cola, 2=\colb, 3=\colc},
        before reading={
            \begin{table}
                \centering
                \begin{tabular}{llr}
                    \toprule
                },
                command={\csviffirstrow
                    {\textbf{\cola} & \textbf{\colb} & \textbf{\colc}}
                    {\addtocounter{csvrow}{-1}\hyperref[sec:a-\thecsvrow]{\cola}\addtocounter{csvrow}{1} & \colb & \colc}
                },
                late after line=\\,
                late after first line=\\\midrule,
                late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
                after reading={
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Liste des entités}
                \label{tab:variables}
            \end{table}
        }
    }
    \end{landscape}
    
    
    
    \subsection{Variable 1}\label{sec:a-1}
    \dots
    
    \subsection{Variable 2}\label{sec:a-2}
    \dots
    
    \subsection{Variable 3}\label{sec:a-3}
    \dots
    
    \subsection{Variable 4}\label{sec:a-4}
    \dots\newline

\csvautobooktabular{macrodata.csv} 
   

    
\end{document}
```

Consequently, I just moved the `csvautobooktabular` command to the end of the document and surprisingly, in the second case, it gave me a table that looks like this:

[image]

Clearly, in the second test macros inside the data file are not functional anymore. Why is this and where is my mistake?

Comment: \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

Comment: Caused by the same reason as [punctuation - Why do the less than symbol (<) and the greater than symbol (>) appear wrong as upside down exclamation (¡) or question mark (¿)? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/why-do-the-less-than-symbol-and-the-greater-than-symbol-appear-wrong-as?noredirect=1&lq=1) and/or [verbatim - \string\noindent outputs a quotation mark " instead of a backslash \ - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648973/string-noindent-outputs-a-quotation-mark-instead-of-a-backslash)

Comment: Ah actually, you want to interpret the macros...

Comment: yes, I want and it works in the first case ... I don't understand... Moreover if i put 2* the `csvautobooktabular` (combining the two test), the first work the second not anymore ...

Comment: Scope: When a value is set, it is not unset/reset on next usage if it is global; if it is local, the local value is dropped when the grouping ends and the global value (if any) becomes visible, unless the local code is setting values globally.

Answer (score 1):

The option key `respect all` converts all special characters to ordinary text.

Use `respect none` to make them special again.

[image: csvsimple]

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{macrodata.csv}
type,description,content
M,A nice \textbf{formula}, $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{x} = \ln|x|+c$
G,A \textcolor{red}{colored} ball, {\tikz \shadedraw [shading=ball] (0,0) circle (.5cm);}
M,\textbf{Another} formula, $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$
\end{filecontents*}    


\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    clé,nom,valeur
    var1,numeric,32+1
    var2,string,"text"
    var3,float,3.14-x
    var4,Latex,test
\end{filecontents*}



\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{book}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[legacy]{csvsimple}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}


\csvautobooktabular{macrodata.csv} 


     \csvloop{
        file=data.csv,
        respect all,
        separator=comma,
        no head,
        column names={1=\cola, 2=\colb, 3=\colc},
        before reading={
            \begin{table}
                \centering
                \begin{tabular}{llr}
                    \toprule
                },
                command={\csviffirstrow
                    {\textbf{\cola} & \textbf{\colb} & \textbf{\colc}}
                    {\addtocounter{csvrow}{-1}\hyperref[sec:a-\thecsvrow]{\cola}\addtocounter{csvrow}{1} & \colb & \colc}
                },
                late after line=\\,
                late after first line=\\\midrule,
                late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
                after reading={
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Liste des entités}
                \label{tab:variables}
            \end{table}
        }
    }

respect all

\csvautobooktabular{macrodata.csv} 
   
repect none

\csvautobooktabular[respect none]{macrodata.csv} 

    
\end{document}
```

---

Addendum:

Slightly tidied up the csvloop code, taking into account automatic key settings.

[image: version 2]

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{macrodata.csv}
type,description,content
M,A nice \textbf{formula}, $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{x} = \ln|x|+c$
G,A \textcolor{red}{colored} ball, {\tikz \shadedraw [shading=ball] (0,0) circle (.5cm);}
M,\textbf{Another} formula, $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$
\end{filecontents*}    


\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    clé,nom,valeur
    var1,numeric,32+1
    var2,string,"text"
    var3,float,3.14-x
    var4,Latex,test
\end{filecontents*}



\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{book}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[legacy]{csvsimple}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}


\csvautobooktabular{macrodata.csv} 


     \csvloop{
        file=data.csv,
%        respect all,
        separator=comma,
        no head,
        before table={
                \begin{table}
                \centering
        },
        tabular={llr},
        table head={
                \toprule
        },
        table foot={\bottomrule},
        column names={1=\cola, 2=\colb, 3=\colc},
        command={\csviffirstrow
                    {\textbf{\cola} & \textbf{\colb} & \textbf{\colc}}
                    {\addtocounter{csvrow}{-1}\hyperref[sec:a-\thecsvrow]{\cola}\addtocounter{csvrow}{1} & \colb & \colc}
                },
                    after first line=\\\midrule,
        late after first line=,
        after table={
           \caption{Liste des entités}
           \label{tab:variables}
            \end{table}
                            },
    }

\csvautobooktabular{macrodata.csv} 
   
\csvautobooktabular[respect none]{macrodata.csv} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: If there are no special characters in the data, `respect all` option is not really needed.