# Why does '\string' convert '\' to "?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

On page 40 of the **TeXbook**, it says, `\string\cs` will produce tokens to be calssied to 12. But `\string\TeX` will produce `"TeX" as

[image]

I once thought that the result should be `\TeX`. Why is there `"TeX`?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96620/

Comment: @Niranjan Yes. Thanks a lot.